# Add Link As a version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement that there is one list and it store an agreement and that agreement is renewed every year. But they need the old history as a hyperlink on the display form of the list for example:if one item is updated 3 times they need 3 hyperlink on the display form

Thank you for help

Comment: It depends a lot on which version of SharePoint you are using and whether you are using modern or classic list "mode"

Comment: Using on premise SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-line column to contain your link and turn "append changes" for the column. Then you would have each link change displayed on the display form along with a timestamp of when the change occurred. Note: Append changes requires versioning to be enabled on the list.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion and i will check it